# Exception thrown in production, but not development (pluck() on null)

Tags: laravel, exception, collections, laravel-5.6

I've encountered a strange error that has me scratching my head.

I am using a package that stores meta information in a meta table. So my models have a meta relation. The package uses this simple method to retrieve meta data.

```
public function getAllMeta()
{
    return collect($this->meta->pluck('value', 'key'));
}
```

So, what you would expect is a collection of meta data if it exists, **or** an empty collection, right? That's what it displays on my local development server. It is my understanding that when attempting to retrieve data from a relation, it will return null if there is no related record.

However, when in production, if there is not a meta relationship (no data), it returns this exception: `Call to a member function pluck() on null`

I can't figure out why this is happening.

- The prod and dev are both using Laravel `5.6.26`.
- Both `composer.json` files are *identical*. I used a diff checker to verify.
- Both prod and dev have had `composer update` run to ensure all dependencies are *identical*.

So, what am I missing? The same code returns an empty collection in dev and throws an exception in prod?

Comment: I assume prod is running with real-world data. How close to real-world is the data in dev?

Comment: What relation type is meta?

Comment: @cHao The data is identical in the meta table in both dev and prod.



@Devon The relationship type is ``morphTo``, which is set in the package. (https://github.com/appstract/laravel-meta)

Comment: It looks like `meta` should have parens after it. Doesn't explain why you're seeing differences in the two environments, but it might help with the immediate problem. You've checked the PHP setup on both machines to make sure they're identical as well? Including versions, php.ini, extensions...?

Comment: @Mark morphTo shouldn't return a collection.  It'll return null or a model.

Comment: @cHao Can you add your last comment concerning the parenthesis as an answer so I can mark it correct. It seems to be a problem with the repo - so I've submitted a pull request to fix it.

Comment: @Mark: Done. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `meta` in that method should have parens after it. (`meta` is a method in the `Metable` trait, not a field.)

Doesn't really explain why you're seeing differences in the two environments, but it might help with the immediate problem.